# Installation of Python and Spyder on new MacBook Pro with M1 max processor

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, spyder, apple-m1

I recently got myself a new MacBook Pro with the M1 processor. I found myself struggling to install Python and Spyder.

- I found out that the Mac comes with Python 2.7
- I installed Spyder using the .dmg file. It natively runs Python 3.9 within Spyder. If I understood it correctly this uses Rosetta. Therefore I installed Python 3.10 which does run on my M1 processor directly. Also I installed all the required packages so that my script runs fine in my terminal.

However, if I choose to run my script in Spyder, using Python 3.10 which not within the Spyder folder I get the following error. I hope someone can help me with advice for the installation of Python, Spyder and packages.

Version of Python2:
Python 2.7.18 (Comes with the Mac)

Version of Python3:
Python 3.10.1

Version of Spyder:
Spyder 5.2.1
Version of packages within Spyder:
Python 3.9.5 64-bit | Qt 5.12.10 | PyQt5 5.12.3 | Darwin 21.2.0

Installed packages on Mac using pip3 list:
Package           Version

---

appnope           0.1.2
backcall          0.2.0
cloudpickle       2.0.0
cycler            0.11.0
debugpy           1.5.1
decorator         5.1.1
entrypoints       0.3
et-xmlfile        1.1.0
fonttools         4.28.5
ipykernel         6.7.0
ipython           7.31.0
jedi              0.18.1
jupyter-client    7.1.0
jupyter-core      4.9.1
kiwisolver        1.3.2
matplotlib        3.5.1
matplotlib-inline 0.1.3
nest-asyncio      1.5.4
numpy             1.22.0
openpyxl          3.0.9
packaging         21.3
pandas            1.3.5
parso             0.8.3
pexpect           4.8.0
pickleshare       0.7.5
Pillow            9.0.0
pip               21.3.1
prompt-toolkit    3.0.24
ptyprocess        0.7.0
Pygments          2.11.2
pyparsing         3.0.6
python-dateutil   2.8.2
pytz              2021.3
pyzmq             22.3.0
scipy             1.7.3
setuptools        58.1.0
six               1.16.0
spyder-kernels    2.2.1
tornado           6.1
traitlets         5.1.1
wcwidth           0.2.5
wurlitzer         3.0.2

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our FAQ](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) to learn how to connect the Spyder macOS app (which seems you already installed) with an external Python environment, so you can use packages that don't come with it.